# Remember dropdown and Validate fields in datable

Tags: jquery, laravel, datatable, laravel-blade, dropdown

The first doubt is how to remember the selected dropdowns when i need to go back in my browser? I have several fields, i put the required data and select all the dropdowns. If there was some error, redirect to the same page with the specific error and all the fields completed, but the dropdown not, i gotta to select again. It's very annoying..
I'm using Laravel with Blade. One example of my select is the next:

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="country_id"> {{{ trans('provider.countries') }}} <span class="required">*</span></label>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="input-group btn-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <i class="fa fa-th-list"></i>
                    </span>
                    {!! Form::select('country_id', $countries, old('country_id'), array('class' => 'form-control', 'required', 'id' => 'select_country', 'placeholder'=>'Seleccione un País', 'autocomplete'=>'off')) !!}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

The other side, i got a datatable with 4 columns, 1 with select and 2 with inpput numbers. When i add the first row, the fields validations works ok, but when i add more than one row, this validations don't work..
The code is the next

```
<div class="table-responsive table-striped table-bordered table-condensed">
    <table class="table table-receipts invoice-items" id="receipt-table">
      <thead>
        <tr class="h5 text-dark">
          <th id="cell-item" class="text-weight-semibold vertical-center">Producto</th>
          <th id="cell-store" class="text-center text-weight-semibold absolute-center">Sucursal</th>
          <th id="cell-price" class="text-center text-weight-semibold absolute-center">Precio Unitario</th>
          <th id="cell-qty" class="text-center text-weight-semibold absolute-center">Cantidad</th>
          <th id="cell-delete" class="text-center text-weight-semibold absolute-center">Acciones</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr class="hide default-row-product">
          <td class="col-md-4 text-weight-semibold text-dark vertical-center">
            <input type="hidden" name="products[]">
          </td>
          <td class="col-md-2 text-center">
            {!! Form::select('stores[]', $stores, '', array('class' => 'form-control', 'required', 'placeholder'=>'Seleccionar', 'id'=>'stores_id')) !!}
          </td>
          <td class="col-md-1 text-center">
            <input type="number" name="prices[]" class="form-control" min="1" step="0.1" id="prices_id" required>
          </td>
          <td class="col-md-1 text-center">
            <input type="number" name="quantities[]" class="form-control" min="1" step="0.1" id="quantities_id" required>
            <td class="col-md-1 text-center">
              <button type="button" class="mb-xs mt-xs mr-xs btn btn-xs btn-danger" id="button-delete-product"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
```

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

Answer for the first question:
You must store selected option in local storage or cookie:

```
// store value in local storage
$('select[name="country_id"]').change(function() {
    localStorage.setItem('selected', this.value);
});

// restore selected value from local storage after page was loaded
if(localStorage.getItem('selected')){
    $('select[name="country_id"]').val(localStorage.getItem('selected'));
}
```

Or you can use session. In the controller after validation data put selected option in the session.

```
if($validator->fails) {
    return Redirect:to('/form')->with('selected', Input::get('question_id');
}
```

And in the View use jQuery:

```
@if(Session::has('selected')
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('select[name="country_id"]').val("{{ Session::get('selected') }}");
});
@endif
```

EDIT:
Validation of array of inputs (prices):

```
$prices = Input::get('prices');
// create array for each price input
for($i = 0; $i <= count($prices); $i++){
    $rules['prices.' . $i] = 'required|numeric|between:0,100'; 
}

$validator = Validator::make($prices, $rules);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I'll try your code later. Look at the datatable tbody, every field is required with interval of values. When i add the second-n rows, this validations don't work. I confirm the form, redirect the page and then show me the error validation with the requests.